# Getting error in Cloudshell: Connect-AzAccount: InteractiveBrowserCredential authentication failed

Tags: azure

I have an existing paid Azure subscription. SOmehow, I failed to pay my bills and subscription got deactivated and then I paid and activated again

But after this incident, I am getting one strange error in Cloudshell as follows:
a) From my Win 10 machine, I opened Chrome/ Edge browser
b) Logged in to Azure Portal
c) Opened Cloud shell and Opened PWSH mode
d) Types in Connect-AZAccount

Getting following warning and then an error:

--> WARNING: Unable to acquire token for tenant 'organizations'
--> Connect-AzAccount: InteractiveBrowserCredential authentication failed: Unable to open a web page using xdg-open. See inner exception for details. Possible causes for this error are: xdg-open is not installed or it cannot find a way to open an url - make sure you can open a web page by invoking from a terminal: xdg-open https://www.bing.com

This never happened earlier and I always used before normally. Also I tried with some other Window systems. Same error. But when I tried to use installed Powershell it works as charm. Please advise what went wrong

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use Cloud Shell, then you don't need to use this command to connect to Azure.Your Azure Cloud Shell session is already authenticated for the environment, subscription, and tenant that launched the Cloud Shell session.

Please see the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/get-started-azureps?view=azps-5.0.0#sign-in-to-azure)：

> Sign in interactively with the Connect-AzAccount cmdlet. Skip this
> step if you use Cloud Shell. Your Azure Cloud Shell session is already
> authenticated for the environment, subscription, and tenant that
> launched the Cloud Shell session.

Comment: HI,

Agreed. The problem is not when I am launching Cloudshell after loggin  to my Portal.
I have two concerns then:
a) I have been using cloud shell for last 6 months and and always able to run Connect-AZAccount without error. Then why Now suddenly it started to give me error?
b) Sometimes while running time extensive Powershell comamnds in Cloudshell, I get following error.
Example:
 Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName $rg -Name webServer2 -CommandId 'RunShellScript' -ScriptPath 'vmconfig.sh'
     Invoke-AzVMRunCommand: Long running operation failed with status 'Unauthorized'.